# Setting selected item in select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select

I tried everything here but nothing works. I would like to set `Yes` as selected at the start. For now it has one empty option and then `Yes` and `No`.

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : someForm.aktivan.$invalid && !someForm.active.$pristine }">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Jep:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select class="form-control" name="ak" id="ak" ng-model="operater.ak" ng-options="o.value as o.option for o in items" required></select>
        <p ng-show="someForm.aktivan.$error.required && !someForm.aktivan.$pristine" class="help-block">Change the values</p>

    </div>
</div>
```

Its gets it from :

```
$scope.items = [
    {
        value: 1,
        option: 'Yes'
    },
    {
        value: 0,
        option: 'No'
    }
];
```

Comment: one empty option what does it mean ??

Comment: @WasiqMuhammad is means that by default nothing is selected.

Comment: it means that it has no value, its empty space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option's `value` attribute is a string so you need to make sure that the `value` in the json is a string as well

```
$scope.items = [{value:"1", option:'Yes'},{value:"0", option:'No'}];
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks to @dfsq's great comment, all you have to do is set a default value to the `ngModel` - Either **1** OR **0**. You DON'T have to change the `value` of the items in your json to strings, leave them as they are.

Comment: Original model was fine, not necessary to use "1" and "0". Just set `ngModel` to `1` or `0`.

Comment: @dfsq Are you sure angular can tell between numbers and strings when used in that manner?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. But don't wonder, try it yourself: http://plnkr.co/edit/bj0ZyWVBcKQoKzRIGgO0?p=preview

Comment: @dfsq Thank you. I'll delete my answer soon

Comment: And you you still wonder how: Angular stores type information in the option's value: `<option label="Yes" value="number:1">Yes</option>`.

Comment: Don't delete, it is correct, just improve it a little, it is okay. I upvoted best answers, so keep it or make it better if you want.

Comment: That's a real eye opener! Thanks again

Comment: dfsq answer is correct, all i did was  setting model to value $scope.operater = {ak:1};

Answer (score 2):

Can try it

In html:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="operater.ak" ng-options="o.value as o.option for o in items" required></select>
```

in controller:

```
$scope.operater = {ak : 1};
$scope.items = [{value:1, option:'Yes'},{value:0, option:'No'}];
```

[PLUNKER DEMO LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/clwzOWwgY6JE8NiJzTLX?p=preview)

Comment: It was typo,  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     $scope.operater.ak=0
```

this will set value